# transferring data from one page to the next

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, I am trying to pass data from one page to another. Basically I get data from an api, then layout the page categories and their details based on that data.

Each one of those details is a link, and when pressed, sends ONLY those details to a template page, which takes the data and lays out the page.

```
    var app = angular.module('example', [require 'angular-route']);

    app.controller('example_ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, 
    $http){
        $http.get('example_data.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.response = data;
        });
    }]);
```

The above would allow me to grab the data from the api end point. I understand that much. But how I can transfer that data via a repeated link in the html is where im getting confused.

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='item in response'>
            <a href='?????????'>
                <p>{{item.title}}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Are you asking about sharing data between controllers?

Comment: Yeah, I would imagine that is the case. It would probably be easier to do it that way.

Comment: to send data from one page to another or should I say one controller to another...you either have to get the next page data from an api and if you don't have an api for getting that data, you can save the data obtained in the first page in an angular service and then get the data from that angular service in the next controller.

Comment: Where do you want to send data from? and where you want to receive it? Your question doesn't have these things

Comment: lets say i want to get a name from the api. I type the name in a search, and the name comes up. I then click that name, because its a link, and it takes me to another page that gives me details about that name. The second page is populating the information based on what i clicked in the first. make sense?

Comment: can u show the response coming from your api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach here is to use a service and inject it in your controller

I'm assuming you're using angular 1

```
app.service('yourService', function() {
  var yourList = [];

  var get = function(){
      return yourList ;
  };

 var add = function(list) {
      yourList.push(list);
  };

  var getSpecific = function(x){
      return yourList[x] ;
  };

  return {
    get : get ,
    getSpecific: getSpecific,
    add: add
  };

});
```

In your controller you reuse the information in your service

```
app.controller('example_ctrl', function($scope, yourService) {
    $scope.response= yourService.get();
});
```